# longtable, how to apply greek language?

Tags: longtable, languages, greek

I need to have for all my tables the labels "*Continued on next page*" and "*Continued from previous page*" in greek. Is that possible?

I know that for each table I can define *\endhead \endfirsthead \endfoot \endlastfoot*. But I'd like to define it only once and not for each table.

Comment: longtable has no global settings, just add the text to the table, as you would in English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you'd find this solution interesting, but it uses the **longtblr** environment from the **[tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)** package. If you want table breaks and captions to be automatically created in your own language (I'm using Italian in the example since I don't know Greek), you can do the following:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \tblrcontfootname { Continua ~ nella ~ pagina ~ successiva }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \tblrcontheadname { ( Continua ) }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\vspace*{17cm} % Random space added
% solely to ensure the table reaches
% the bottom of the page

\begin{longtblr}{cccc}
Persona & Pizza & Pasta & Mandolino \\
Antonio & Sì & No & No \\
Giorgio & Sì & No & No \\
Margherita & Sì & No & No \\
Luchino & Sì & No & No
\end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

The code enclosed by %%% allows you to globally modify the two expressions according to your preferences.
In my case, it's what transforms this:
[image: original version]
into this:
[image]